# How to get a difference between two query result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two queries. The output for the first query is the total sales quantity for all Brands and the output for the second query is the total sales quantity only for 'New' Brands.
I need to create only one query (By merging below two queries: Query1 & Query2) where we can see the total sales of 'New' brands per Region,  total sales of All brands per region and a new column named difference (Total sales quantity of All brands- Total sales quantity of New brands) side by side.

Expected Output :

| InvoiceDate | Brand | Region | Quantity for 'New' Brand | Quantity for All Brand | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021/10/01 | New | A | 40 | 100 | 60 |
| 2021/10/01 | New | B | 10 | 90 | 80 |
| 2021/10/01 | New | C | 50 | 150 | 100 |
| 2021/10/01 | New | D | 30 | 200 | 170 |

These are my queries:

Query1:

```
SELECT InvoiceDate, Brand, Region, Quantity From TotalSales // For All Brands
```

Query2:

```
SELECT InvoiceDate, Brand, Region, Quantity From TotalSales where Brand='New' // For New Brands
```

Comment: The first query, by definition, includes the data from the second already... The second query is just the first with a `WHERE` clause to filter the rows. Are you therefore saying you want to duplicate the rows where the value of `Brand` is `'New'`? That isn't what your expected results show.

Comment: Actually, my goal is to obtain a filtered dataset only for New Brands (So that the total dataset size is smaller) where I can also get the total sales quantity of that Region to compare side by side.

Comment: At Expected Result Set : "Quantity for 'New' Brand" &  "Quantity for All Brand" are basically the same column as 'Quantity' from 'TotalSales' Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the quantity for brand = 'new' and the total quantity for all brands and compare the two.

One way to achieve this is conditional aggregation:

```
select
  invoicedate,
  'New' as brand,
  region,
  sum(case when brand = 'New' then quantity else 0 end) as qty_new,
  sum(quantity) as qty_all,
  sum(quantity) - sum(case when brand = 'New' then quantity else 0 end) as diff
from totalsales
group by invoicedate, region
having sum(case when brand = 'New' then quantity else 0 end) > 0
order by invoicedate, region;
```

Another is a join

```
with qnew as
(
  select invoicedate, brand, region, quantity
  from totalsales
  where brand = 'New'
)
, qall as
(
  select invoicedate, region, sum(quantity) as total
  from totalsales
  group by invoicedate, region
)
select
  qnew.*, qall.total, qall.total- qnew.quantity as diff 
from qnew
join qall on qall.invoicedate = qnew.invoicedate
         and qall.brand = qnew.brand
         and qall.region = qnew.region
order by qnew.invoicedate, qnew.brand, qnew.region;
```

Comment: Hi @Thorsten, Thanks for your answer. I am facing a problem like, we have sales for new brands on 2021-08-02 , 2021-08-04 , 2021-08-07 (Three days in total on August 2021) But we have sales for other brands except for New Brands for every day on August 2021. But this query with conditional aggregation is fetching "qty_all" rows only with the matching invoice dates from new brands.Thus the total qty for all brands per region is smaller than the actual

Comment: Your comment under your request made it sound like you want exactly that: only date/region for which a 'New' entry exists. If you want other date/regions, too, then remove the `HAVING` clause. For the second query you'd change the inner join to `from qall left outer join qnew on ...` and use `COALESCE(qnew.quantity, 0)`to make the missing sums zeros.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of doing this...
First - I don't think you want the "Brand" column in your result. That doesn't make must sense. Also, I think you are going to want a summation for the AllBrands total...

1. Use subqueries

```
select allBrands.InvoiceDate, allBrands.Region, newBrands.Quantity as NewQuantity, allBrands.Quantity as allQuantity, allBrands.Quantity-newBrands.Quantity as Difference
FROM
(SELECT InvoiceDate, Region, SUM(Quantity) as Quantity From TotalSales GROUP BY InvoiceDate, Region) as allBrands
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT InvoiceDate, Region, Quantity From TotalSales where Brand='New') as NewBrands ON NewBrands.InvoiceDate = allBrands.InvoiceDate AND NewBrands.Region = AllBrands.Region
```

or 2. use temp tables

```
SELECT InvoiceDate, Region, SUM(Quantity) as Quantity INTO #allSales From TotalSales GROUP BY InvoiceDate, Region;
SELECT InvoiceDate, Region, Quantity INTO #newSales From TotalSales where Brand='New';
select allBrands.InvoiceDate, allBrands.Region, newBrands.Quantity as NewQuantity, allBrands.Quantity as allQuantity, allBrands.Quantity-newBrands.Quantity as Difference
FROM #allBrands allBrands
LEFT OUTER JOIN #newBrands newBrands ON NewBrands.InvoiceDate = allBrands.InvoiceDate AND NewBrands.Region = AllBrands.Region;
```

Comment: Hi @CMGeek , Thanks for your answer. I am facing a problem like, we have sales for new brands on  2021-08-02 , 2021-08-04 , 2021-08-07 (Three days in total on August 2021) But we have sales for other brands except for New Brands for every day on August 2021. So when we are joining allbrands and newbrands with invoice date , total quantity from all brands are fetched only with the matching invoice dates from new brands.Thus the total qty per region is smaller than the actual

Comment: The you will need to use a LEFT JOIN instead of a regular JOIN. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple conditional aggregation (`SUM`) on the data such as this:

```
DECLARE @TotalSales TABLE (InvoiceDate DATE, Brand NVARCHAR(16), Region NCHAR(1), Quantity INT)

INSERT INTO
    @TotalSales(
        InvoiceDate,
        Brand,
        Region,
        Quantity
    )
VALUES      ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'A', 20),
            ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'A', 20),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'A', 30),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'A', 30),
            ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'B', 10),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'B', 30),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'B', 50),
            ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'C', 50),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'C', 100),
            ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'D', 10),
            ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'D', 10),
            ('10/1/2021', 'New', 'D', 10),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'D', 100),
            ('10/1/2021', 'Old', 'D', 70),
            ('11/1/2021', 'Old', 'A', 50)

;WITH Data AS (
    SELECT
        ts.InvoiceDate,
        ts.Region,
        SUM(ts.Quantity) AS QuantityAll,
        SUM(CASE WHEN ts.Brand = 'New' THEN ts.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS QuantityNew
    FROM
        @TotalSales ts
    GROUP BY
        ts.InvoiceDate,
        ts.Region
)

SELECT
    d.InvoiceDate,
    d.Region,
    d.QuantityAll,
    d.QuantityNew,
    d.QuantityAll - d.QuantityNew AS TheDifference
FROM
    Data d
ORDER BY
    d.InvoiceDate,
    d.Region
```

I used a CTE so that we don't have to repeat the conditional `SUM(CASE WHEN...` for subtracting between `QuantityNew` and `QuantityAll`.

Output is:

> ```
> InvoiceDate   Region  QuantityAll QuantityNew TheDifference
> 2021-10-01    A       100         40          60
> 2021-10-01    B       90          10          80
> 2021-10-01    C       150         50          100
> 2021-10-01    D       200         30          170
> 2021-11-01    A       50          0           50
> ```